# GPS coordinates change too frequently

Tags: android, gps

I have used the following code to check GPS coordinates, but problem is that if i am standing at same place the coordinates changes and distance is anywhere between 4 to 20 mts.
I want to change it only when I have moved min 10 mtrs.

```
    locationManager_gps = (LocationManager) this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager_gps.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                    new MyLocationListener_gps());

class MyLocationListener_gps implements LocationListener {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            clat = location.getLatitude();
            clon = location.getLongitude();

            if (clat != plat || clon != plon) {
                float[] results = new float[3];
                Location.distanceBetween(plat, plon, clat, clon, results);

                if (flag_gps == 0) {
                    flag_gps = 1;
                } else {
                    GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (clat * 1E6),
                            (int) (clon * 1E6));
                    mapView.getController().animateTo(geoPoint);
                    draw = new MyOverLay(geoPoint);
                    mapView.getOverlays().add(draw);

                    dist_mtr += results[0];

                }
                plat = clat;
                plon = clon;
            }
        }
```

If I use 50 as min distance between updates then it is working fine. I also tried making it 30 but also data was wrong over a period of 4 km while traveling in car.

Please suggest what I should do.

Comment: I have given a random value to plat and plon above in may code and made flag_gps=0 just to skip first location change update

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this too, when taking several location readings and I haven't moved. You can get variable results with different accuracies.
You could try taking, say, 10 location readings and take the one with the best accuracy and disregard the rest. Then when taking the next reading, make sure it is located at a distance which is twice the accuracy of the previous location. For example, if your first location has an accuracy of, say 16 meters, make sure the next reading is at least 32 meters away from the previous location AND has an accuracy better than 32 meters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the minTime and minDistance in combination.  You pass zero and zero for both, so the min time between updates will be at least zero seconds and the min distance will be zero.  So set minTime to a reasonable time and minDistance to 10 for ten meters.

```
locationManager_gps.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                    new MyLocationListener_gps());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic bullet to solve this... the gps is not 100% accurate and you will always have different readings every time you get a new location update.

You can minimize the issue using a low pass filter for the location values:

```
clat = plat + (clat-plat) * 0.2; // you should adjust the 0.2 value to the best results
clon = plon + (clon-plon) * 0.2;
....
//your code
....
plat = clat;
plon = clon;
```

With this the effect of sudden changes to the values will be minimized, which is good for the fake changes in position, but it will also delay the response to the real changes in the positions when the device is moving. You should choose careffuly the value of the constant multiplying (0.2 above) to have the best results.

You can even do better, using a variable instead of a constant, and adjust the value of it based on the accuracy of the loaction update (good accuracy you make the variable close to 1, pour accuracy you make the variable close to 0)

good luck